# Windows 10 Mobile Collection View (Dynamic positioned containers)

Tags: c#, windows-10-mobile

Is there any way to create Collection View (like in IOS) for Windows Phone?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

I would like to achive something like below. So boxes will be positioned according to orientation/screen size.

In another word, it should be like floating div in HTML.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually (or at least previously) in XAML this is implemented using [WrapPanel](http://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html). UWP doesn't have built-in WrapPanel but one option is to use [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) instead. For example:

```
<Grid>
    <GridView Margin="24">

        <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="2"/>
        <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="2"/>
        <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="2"/>
        <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="2"/>
        <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="2"/>
        <Border Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="2"/>

    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Will output the following in portrait:

[image: Portrait GridView]

And the following in landscape:

[image: GridView landscape]

If you like the idea behind WrapPanel, you can get some third party WrapPanels for UWP. Here's couple links:

- [UniversalWrapPanel (for 8.1, but should work with 10).](https://github.com/gregstoll/UniversalWrapPanel)
- [ComponentOne's WrapPanel (Commercial)](http://our.componentone.com/2013/03/07/winrt-xaml-part-10-layout-panels/)

Comment: Great, this is what I am looking for.